# I have implemented Real time data editing in my matDialog using angular but I am not getting any response

Tags: angular

I have developed a mean stack app that I want to fetch data from server and be able to edit it using a matDialog in angular. My API works fine but I don't get any response after I have edited my data on the table could you help me to find & resolve this issue.I just want to edit the first name

**Here is my uservice.ts**

````
```import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import{ User } from '../model/User.model'
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { from, Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  users : User[];
  updateUsers = new Subject<User[]>();
  selectedUser : User;


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getAdmins()
{
 return this.http.get(environment.api_url + 'admins')

}

//fetch students from suasis
getAllstudents()
{
  return this.http.get(environment.api_url + 'admins')
}

//update user info
UpdateuserInfo(admin:User)
{
  return this.http.patch(environment.api_url + `/${admin.firstname}`,admin);
}

}```
````

**Here is my Dialogedit.component.ts**

````
```import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { User } from '../model/User.model';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialogedit',
  templateUrl: './dialogedit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialogedit.component.css'],
  providers: [UserService]
})
export class DialogeditComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogeditComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: User, private uservice:UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  OnEdit(admin:User)
  {
    this.uservice.UpdateuserInfo(admin);
  }

}```
````

**Here is my DialoEdit.component.html**

````
```<div mat-dialog-content>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.firstname" placeholder="First Name">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close] (click)="OnEdit(admin)" cdkFocusInitial>Update</button>
</div>```
````

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't get any response"? what are you expecting?

Comment: Did you added your _app-dialogedit_ selector in the declaration and entryComponents array of app.module.ts?

Comment: @RafiHenig i expect data to change upon editing the first name

Comment: yes brother @Manmohan_singh

Answer (score 0):

Inside `ngOnInit()` function you have to call a refresh function that gets the data from API. call `getAdmins()` or `getAllStudents()` depending upon your requirement . In order to template this data in HTML , I am assuming you are using MatTableDataSource type object. If not ,  create a **MatTableDataSource** object , Subscribe to the data received from get requests and display data inside the callback function.

For example,
Your component html should display data like this,

```
<mat-table [dataSource] = "listData" >
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns:displayColumns"></mat-row>
 <ng-container matColumnDef="STUDENTID" >
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>StudentID</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.STUDENTID}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
 <ng-container matColumnDef="STUDENTNAME">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>StudentName</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.STUDENTNAME}}</mat-cell>
   </ng-container>

 </mat-table>
```

And your component.ts should have the ngOnInit() configured like this.

```
 listData : MatTableDataSource<any>;
  displayColumns : string[] = ['STUDENTID','STUDENTNAME'];


 ngOnInit() {
    this.refresStuList();
  }

  refreshStuList() {
    this.service.getAllStudents().subscribe(data =>{
      this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(data);


    });
```

Comment: am new to angular would you mind showing me how me ,